# Modal Box won't open on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote a script that opens up an enlarged image in a modal box when you click on the smaller one but for some reason when I try to click on the small image the modal box does not open. My website uses bootstrap but I have written my own CSS to create the modal as the bootstrap is not providing me with what I want.

I opened my inspector in Chrome and I got an error with my JavaScript

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

This is on line 1 of the javascript

**HTML&PHP**

```php
<div class="bgmd">
    <div class="ctmod">
        <div class="xbutton">&times</div>
        <?php
            echo "<img src='images/car22.jpg'/>";//Large Image
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
echo "<a href='#' id='big'><img src='images/car".$id.".jpg' class='img-thumbnail center-block'/></a>";//Smaller Image
```

**CSS**

```css
.bgmd{
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
    align-items: center !important;
    display: none !important;
}
.ctmod{
    width: 500px !important;
    height: 300px !important;
    background-color: white !important;
    border-radius: 4px !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    position: relative !important;
}
.xbutton{
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    right: 14px !important;
    font-size: 42px !important;
    transform: rotate(45deg) !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```js
document.getElementById('big').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('.bgmd').style.display = 'flex';
});

document.querySelector('.xbutton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('.bgmd').style.display = 'none';
});
```

Comment: Seems like either `document.getElementById('big')` or `document.querySelector('.xbutton')` are `null`. Can you post the generated HTML code?

Comment: Because the error occures one line 1 it should be `document.getElementById('big')` that is null...

Comment: @jabaa https://jsbin.com/kedawad/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your linked HTML-output there are multiple elements with the ID `big`. This is not valid and therefor you get the error. You should make sure that you have only unique IDs, then your code will work.

Furthermore: Please check double definitions like `display` and if it's really necessary to use so many `!important` statements.

---

If you have multiple elements like this you have to loop over the `#big...` images. To select all elements with an ID that begins with `big` you can use the attribute selector:

```js
var img_triggers = document.querySelectorAll('a[id^="big"]');
```

To style the associated `div.bgmd` you could select the previous element of the clicked anchor:

```js
this.previousElementSibling.style.display = 'flex';
```

For closing via `.xbutton` you also have to loop over all of these buttons and style its grandparent (which is the associated `div.bgmd`):

```js
this.previousElementSibling.style.display = 'flex';
```

**Working example:** (*minified for demonstration, with some dummy data and without `!important`*)

```js
var img_triggers = document.querySelectorAll('a[id^="big"]');
for (let i = 0; i < img_triggers.length; i++) {
  img_triggers[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.previousElementSibling.style.display = 'flex';
  });
}

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.xbutton');
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
  });
}
```

```css
.bgmd {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: none;
}

.ctmod {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.xbutton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 14px;
  font-size: 42px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="bgmd">
  <div class="ctmod">
    <div class="xbutton">&times</div>
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/1/150' />
  </div>
</div>
<a href='#' id='big1'>
  <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/1/50' class='img-thumbnail center-block' />
</a>

<div class="bgmd">
  <div class="ctmod">
    <div class="xbutton">&times</div>
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/2/150' />
  </div>
</div>
<a href='#' id='big2'>
  <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/2/50' class='img-thumbnail center-block' />
</a>

<div class="bgmd">
  <div class="ctmod">
    <div class="xbutton">&times</div>
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/3/150' />
  </div>
</div>
<a href='#' id='big3'>
  <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/3/50' class='img-thumbnail center-block' />
</a>
```

Comment: The reason for the multiple elements with the ID ```big``` is that its generated from a php loop. Its listing with pictures. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: You could add the loop count to the ID. For example: `'<... id="big' . $i . '" ...>'`

Comment: I was able to the ```$id``` variable that is used for the link portion. I think that satisfys the unique ID problem. However Im still not able to get it to work. 
```echo "<a href='#' id='big".$id."'><img src='images/car".$id.".jpg' class='img-thumbnail center-block'/></a>";//```

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work with php code. But it would with the generated html of your updated php code...

Comment: I ended up getting it to work. I think there was some type of conflict with some javascript that made some dropdown menus work for flitering. I rewrote that part and the modal box works great now.

Answer (score 2):

You have the `display` property twice affecting the same element which is conflicting, you should only have `display: none;` without the `!important` rule. Also you have an excessive amount of `!important` rules, they're only necessary when you want to override other styles (typically ones that can't be directly edited)

Answer (score 1):

You set

```css
.bgmd {
  display: none !important;
}
```

which overrides setting the style of the modal to `display: flex`.

Comment: If I take that out it shows to modal when I load the page

Comment: Yes, because you also have `display: flex !important;` 3 lines before. That also hinders JS to change the style display property. Set only `display: none` to initially hide it – without `!important`.

Comment: I made a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/mattweb/pen/BaRyRQj?editors=1111) which shows the basic functionality from your example. Maybe you should consider using some existing script that provides useful features like [a11y-dialog](https://github.com/KittyGiraudel/a11y-dialog).